# scrollLeft bug chrome outside jsfddle

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome

I have a scrollLeft function on a header so it is fixed vertically but scrolls horizontally.  There is a bug in chrome for android where the header scrolls horizontally twice as fast as the rest of the page.

If I view this  example in chrome for android it works as it should.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnLbd0a2/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript'   src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>




<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<style type='text/css'>
#header {
height: 40px;
width: 900px;
background-color: red;

position: fixed;
  z-index: 2; }

#content {
height: 1000px;
width: 900px;
background-color: blue;
top: 50px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1; }
</style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').css('left', 8 - $(this).scrollLeft());
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="header">This is a fixed header that scrolls horizontally</div>
<div id="content">This is blah blah blah blah</div>

</body>


</html>
```

When I implement the code on a basic page as this  page, the bug appears.

[simple jsfiddle page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vnLbd0a2/2/show/)

Somehow jsfiddle gets around the bug.

Comment: I have discovered that the bug is not present on jsfiddle because the demo is within an iframe.  The scrollleft function works when within an iframe on my website but not on the website itself.  For example if I source my site within an iframe within my site scrollleft works within the iframe but not on the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Changing
`$('#header').css('left', 8 - $(this).scrollLeft());`

to
`$('#header').css('margin-left', 8 - $(this).scrollLeft());`

and setting the fixed element to `left:auto !important;`

has resolved the issue!!!